# Optimizing SQL connection performance?

Tags: c#, .net, sql, performance, sqlconnection

This is not a question about optimizing a SQL command.  I'm wondering what ways there are to ensure that a SQL connection is kept open and ready to handle a command as efficiently as possible.

What I'm seeing right now is I can execute a SQL command and that command will take ~1s, additional executions will take ~300ms.  This is after the command has previously been executed against the SQL server (from another application instance)... so the SQL cache should be fully populated for the executed query prior to this applications initial execution.  As long as I continually re-execute the query I see times of about 300ms, but if I leave the application idle for 5-10 minutes and return the next request will be back to ~1s (same as the initial request).

Is there a way to via the connection string or some property on the SqlConnection direct the framework to keep the connection hydrated and ready to efficiently handle queries?

Answer (score 2):

Have you checked the execution plan for your procedures. Execution plans I believe are loaded into memory on the Server and then get cleared after certain periods of time or depending on what tables etc are accessed in the procedures. We've had cases where simplifying stored procedures (perhaps splitting them) reduces the amount of work the database server has to do in calculating the plans...and ultimately reduces the first time the procedure is called...You can issue commands to force stored procedures to recompile each time for testing whether you are reducing the initial call time...
We've had cases where the complexity of a stored procedure made the database server continually have to recompile based on different parameters which drastically slowed it down, splitting the SP or simplifying large select statements into multiple update statements etc helped a considerable amount.

other ideas are perhaps intermittently calling a simple getDate() or similar every so often so that the sql server is awake (hope that makes sense)...much the same as keeping an asp.net app in memory in IIS.

Answer (score 2):

The default value for open connections in a .NET connection pool is zero.

You can adjust this value in your connection string to 1 or more:

```
"data source=dbserver;...Asynchronous Processing=true;Min Pool Size=1"
```

See more about these [options in MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xx3tyca(VS.71).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

you keep it open by not closing it. :) but that's not adviseable since connection pooling will handle connection management for you. do you have it enabled?

Answer (score 0):

by default the connection pooling is enabled in ADO .NET. this will be through the connection string used by the application. More info in [Using Connection Pooling with SQL Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xx3tyca(VS.80).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

If you use more than one database connection, it may be more efficent.  Having one database connection means the best possible access speed is always going to be limited sequentially.  Whereas having >1 connections means theres an opportunity there for your compiler to optimize concurrent access a little more.  I guess you're using .NET?

Also if your issuing the same SQL statement repeatedly, its possible your database server is caching the result for a short period of time, therefore making the return of the resultset quicker..